# How can I make quotation marks act as normal text within a regex function?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use regex to extract information from a large text file on google sheets, but within the regex, I'm using quotation marks, and instead of treating everything like the text I want to use, the quotation marks make it so that the regex splits into many different parts. Is there some character I can add to prevent this?

As an example, say I used `=REGEXEXTRACT("name"="",""name"="(\w+)"")`

It would basically split this into:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(
"name"
=
""
,
""
name
"="
(\w+)
"")
```

and would return a formula parse error.

Is there any way I can cancel out certain quotation marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can escape double quotes by... another double quote!

So if your first formula argument is `name"="` and your second formula argument is `"name"="(\w+)"`, you would use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT("name""=""","""name""=""(\w+)""")
```

**Output: (note that I used concatenate to show the expressions)**

[image]